How to have restatable tcolorbox theorem environments, while avoiding labels being multiply defined
I have a document where I would like to define a theorem early on, and then restate the same theorem later on when it comes time to prove it.
Normally this could be done using the thm-restate package. However, the theorems in my document use a tcolorbox environment, so instead I tried using the approach suggested in this answer.
That approach works for restating theorems, but then LaTeX raises warnings about labels being "multiply defined." Because of this error, I cannot then reference the restated theorems correctly.
My question: how can I restate tcolorbox theorems, without running into an issue where labels are duplicated?
Here is a minimum example showcasing the setup and problem:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{magazine}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}

% The tcolorbox theorem
\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{colback=gray!10,colframe=gray!40!black}{theorem}

% Commands to restate the theorem
\newcommand{\recallthm}[2][1]{\par\noindent\useboxarray[#2]{#1}}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{restatablethm}[2]{%
\newboxarray{#2}%
\begin{theorem}[reset box array=#2, store to box array=#2]{#1}{#2}
    \BODY%
\end{theorem}%
\recallthm{#2}%
}

% Other theorem environments might be on the same counter
\newtheorem{lemma}[tcb@cnt@theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

    % The first theorem
    \begin{restatablethm}{Serious Algorithm}{coollabel}
        An example boxed theorem..
    \end{restatablethm}

    \begin{lemma}
        A simple lemma.
    \end{lemma}

    % The restated theorem
    \recallthm{coollabel}

    By \Cref{thm:collabel} we are done. % The reference here does not work (yields ??). 

\end{document}


Adding [nophantom] will remove the duplicate labels, but it also romves the first label.  BTW, the correct label name is  theorem:coollabel and the counter name is tcb@cnt@theorem.

(Disclaimer: I wrote the package, keytheorems, used in the answer below.)
You can use the keytheorems package to integrate amsthm with tcolorbox. It works as expected with hyperref and cleveref. Here is your example adapted to keytheorems.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{keytheorems}

% The tcolorbox theorem
\newkeytheoremstyle{tcbstyle}
  {
    tcolorbox={colback=gray!10,colframe=gray!40!black},
    notebraces={}{},
    headpunct={},
    noteseparator={: },
    headfont=\normalfont,
    bodyfont=\normalfont,
  }
\newkeytheorem{theorem}[style=tcbstyle]

% Other theorem environments might be on the same counter
\newkeytheorem{lemma}[sibling=theorem,style=definition]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[
  note=Serious Algorithm,
  store=coollabel,
  label=thm:coollabel]
An example boxed theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}
    A simple lemma.
\end{lemma}

% The restated theorem
\getkeytheorem{coollabel}

By \Cref{thm:coollabel} we are done.

\end{document}



This uses [nophantom] to create the recallable box, but not the original.  It still generates a warning about duplicate hypertargets, plus one about the shipout box.  \Cref doesn't work at all, even though a theorem:coollabel@cref label was created.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{magazine}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}

% The tcolorbox theorem
\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{colback=gray!10,colframe=gray!40!black}{theorem}

% Commands to restate the theorem
\newcommand{\recallthm}[2][1]{\par\noindent\useboxarray[#2]{#1}}
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{restatablethm}[2]{% print this copy
\newboxarray{#2}%
\begin{theorem}[reset box array=#2, store to box array=#2,nophantom]{#1}{#2}
    \BODY%
\end{theorem}%
\addtocounter{tcb@cnt@theorem}{-1}%
\begin{theorem}{#1}{#2}
    \BODY%
\end{theorem}%
%\recallthm{#2}%
}

% Other theorem environments might be on the same counter
\newtheorem{lemma}[tcb@cnt@theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

    % The first theorem
    \begin{restatablethm}{Serious Algorithm}{coollabel}
        An example boxed theorem..
    \end{restatablethm}

    \begin{lemma}
        A simple lemma.
    \end{lemma}

    % The restated theorem
    \recallthm{coollabel}

    By \ref{theorem:coollabel} we are done. % The reference here does not work (yields ??). 

\end{document}

